# How to use the puzzle package?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use the puzzlelogic package in LaTeX but it has an error because I dont know how to define an environment. Can you help?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},{},{},\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},{},\MoonTL}
\setrow{3}{\Moon}
\setrow{2}{{},\MoonR}
\setrow{1}{{},{},{},\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},\Star,\Cloud,\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},\Star,\MoonTL,{},\Cloud}
\setrow{3}{\Moon,\Cloud,{},{},\Star}
\setrow{2}{\Cloud,\MoonR,{},\Star}
\setrow{1}{\Star,{},\Cloud,\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},{},{},\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},{},\MoonTL}
\setrow{3}{\Moon}
\setrow{2}{{},\MoonR}
\setrow{1}{{},{},{},\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},\Star,\Cloud,\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},\Star,\MoonTL,{},\Cloud}
\setrow{3}{\Moon,\Cloud,{},{},\Star}
\setrow{2}{\Cloud,\MoonR,{},\Star}
\setrow{1}{\Star,{},\Cloud,\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Environment sunandmoon was undefined but I dont know how to define it.

Comment: Did you try with `article`? You shouldn't have `center` if using `standalone`. That said, it works fine for me. I just get a blank first page. Please give the exact error i.e. copy and page it. This will include a line number and a precise message.

Comment: Well, I guess that's why it's a puzzle. ;-) More seriously, if you remove `\end{center}
\begin{center}`, as pointed out by @cfr, your code compiles. Whether or not the output makes sense is another question (at least I am a bit puzzled by the output ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this helps and will, of course, be happy to remove this post if it doesn't.

- As pointed out by @cfr, you need to get rid of the `center` statements to make the code compilable.
- After that I was puzzled by the outcome (beyond the way it should be because it is a puzzle), but if one removes `[tikz]` from `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`, the outcome is just as puzzling as it is supposed to be.

This leads to the proposal

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},{},{},\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},{},\MoonTL}
\setrow{3}{\Moon}
\setrow{2}{{},\MoonR}
\setrow{1}{{},{},{},\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}
&  
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},\Star,\Cloud,\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},\Star,\MoonTL,{},\Cloud}
\setrow{3}{\Moon,\Cloud,{},{},\Star}
\setrow{2}{\Cloud,\MoonR,{},\Star}
\setrow{1}{\Star,{},\Cloud,\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}\\
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},{},{},\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},{},\MoonTL}
\setrow{3}{\Moon}
\setrow{2}{{},\MoonR}
\setrow{1}{{},{},{},\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}
&  
\begin{sunandmoon}
\framepuzzle
\setrow{5}{{},{},\Star,\Cloud,\Moon}
\setrow{4}{{},\Star,\MoonTL,{},\Cloud}
\setrow{3}{\Moon,\Cloud,{},{},\Star}
\setrow{2}{\Cloud,\MoonR,{},\Star}
\setrow{1}{\Star,{},\Cloud,\MoonT}
\end{sunandmoon}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have copied the whole of your code but after compilation, the message is still that the sunandmoon environment is not defined.

Comment: @Thumbolt Well, one possible interpretation is that you do not have the standard `logicpuzzle` package installed. How did you install it? Is it part of your LaTeX installation? When was the last time you updated your LaTeX installation?

Comment: I just use it without any updates for two years. My friend gave me a (USB) portable version of Miktex for my windows. I even dont know how to get it updated.

Comment: @Thumbolt Do you have a LaTeX installation, e.g. MikTeX or TeXLive? These come with update managers. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/121799) how to update MikTeX and here for a [general overview](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/121799).

Comment: I used Miktex with a very small version portable. It requires to pin on the desktop every six months.

Comment: @Thumbolt Sorry, what am I supposed to do with that information?

Comment: Incidentally, removing the `tikz` option is expected to help for the same reason switching to `article` will help.

Comment: @Thumbolt Do you have `logicpuzzle.sty` installed? Which version?

Comment: I am not sure. I have just download the zip file to my C disk on my laptop. There are just dtx file and pdf in this package, no sty file found. 
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/logicpuzzle?lang=en

Comment: I was able to use this package today after the new texlive was installed. Thank you.